# Servicestack with Razor not working -> FORBIDDEN ressource

Tags: razor, servicestack, servicestack-razor

I'm loosing my mind ... wanna use SS Razor feature in an empty web application on my **Win 8.1** machine. Installed via NuGet, added a webpage at the root and get this error:

```
>Forbidden
>Request.HttpMethod: GET
>Request.PathInfo: /default.cshtml
>Request.QueryString: 
>Request.RawUrl: /default.cshtml
>App.DebugLastHandlerArgs: >GET|/default.cshtml|Z:\GIT\MasterThesis\src\AppBlue\AppBlue.Web\default.cshtml
```

I also tried the Razor rockstars sample app from SS - this works perfectly.
So I've copied the web.config but no success. Also run the managed pipeline mode in integrated mode.
**Project is set to .NET 4.5**.
Still doesn't work when I deploy to Azure [here](http://nhaberl.azurewebsites.net)

For completition here my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes for .NET 4.5 see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="ServiceStack.Razor.CSharpRazorBuildProvider, ServiceStack.Razor" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
          <add fileExtension=".cshtml" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
        <add namespace="AppBlue.Web" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc" />
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Any help appreciated!
All the best

**UPDATE**

The installed version of AspNet.WebPages was 2 so I installed the latest version via NuGet and changed the web.config

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

It works fine now, but my custom path -> api doesn't seem to work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>


  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes for .NET 4.5 see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <location path="api" >
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</location>

  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="ServiceStack.Razor.CSharpRazorBuildProvider, ServiceStack.Razor" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
          <add fileExtension=".cshtml" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>




  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<appSettings>
    <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings><system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc" />
    <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
        <add namespace="AppBlue.Web" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor></configuration>
```

The REST calls work but on the root path only.

Comment: Can enable [DebugMode](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#debugmode) then see if there were any StartUp exceptions in `?debug=requestinfo`

Comment: Thanks, couldn't load System.Web.Razor as you can see here http://nhaberl.azurewebsites.net/default.cshtml?debug=requestinfo
But don't know how to resolve ?

Comment: See wiki on [resolving missing Razor Config](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Razor-Notes#missing-razor-configuration)

Comment: Maybe you could give a short explanation how System.Web.WebPages.Razor, System.Web.Razor and SS.Razor are related?
And why RazorRockstars is working without the Version info given ?